# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library (path exist)

Tags: php, shared-libraries, php-7.3, debian-buster

I want to execute a program in a new VM of Debian 10 and I get warnings related to .so loading:

Distribution related specs: Debian 10, php 7.3.11

Execution:

```
./program.php
```

it contains the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
```

here is the lines i modified the the php.ini file:

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```

and here is the return of `ls -l /usr/lib/php/20180731`

```
total 8788
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   34920 oct.  26 16:14 calendar.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14440 oct.  26 16:14 ctype.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92264 oct.  26 16:14 exif.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5429360 oct.  26 16:14 fileinfo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67688 oct.  26 16:14 ftp.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14440 oct.  26 16:14 gettext.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47208 oct.  26 16:14 iconv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47208 oct.  26 16:14 json.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1611912 oct.  26 16:14 mbstring.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  141416 oct.  26 16:14 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  251512 oct.  26 16:14 mysqlnd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  518640 oct.  26 16:14 opcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30824 oct.  26 16:14 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112744 oct.  26 16:14 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  280680 oct.  26 16:14 phar.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39016 oct.  26 16:14 posix.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   34920 oct.  26 16:14 readline.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14440 oct.  26 16:14 shmop.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   96360 oct.  26 16:14 sockets.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22632 oct.  26 16:14 sysvmsg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14440 oct.  26 16:14 sysvsem.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14440 oct.  26 16:14 sysvshm.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22632 oct.  26 16:14 tokenizer.so
```

I cant find the reason php cant open the .so files

I know there were many posts like mine, but they were only path related problem and my paths seems to be corects.

Answer (score 1):

That means your extensions are not in `/usr/lib/php/20180731`

You can check the right path using

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

And make sure your `mysqli.so` and `pdo_mysql` are there

Comment: i just deleted the two lines i added in the php.ini to load the extensions.
my script are still working and the warnings disapeared. the paths i got from your command were the right ones i used